# Jquery Tab add remove

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Tab 1 does not work. Tab 1 is drawn from MySQL table. I want show default tab and add or delete an extra tab and post mysql get inserted tab id append not count?. Can you help?

Visit jsfiddle [jsfiddle.net/datakolay/33aM3/](http://jsfiddle.net/datakolay/33aM3/)

Html

```
 <ul id="tabul">
  <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"><a href="" id="addtab">+</a></li>
   <li id="t21" class="ntabs"> Tab Mysql id 21
    <a href="" id="close21" class="close">&times;</a>
  </li>
   <li id="t22" class="ntabs"> Tab Mysql id 22
    <a href="" id="close22" class="close">&times;</a>
   </li>  
</ul>
<div id="tabcontent">
  <p id="c21">Test</p>    
  <p id="c22">Test</p> 
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
var total_tabs = 0;
total_tabs++;
$("#addtab, #litab").click(function() {
    total_tabs++;
    $("#tabcontent p").hide();
    addtab(total_tabs);
    return false;
});
function addtab(count) {
    var closetab = '<a href="" id="close'+count+'" class="close">&times;</a>';
    $("#tabul").append('<li id="t'+count+'" class="ntabs">Tab Extra &nbsp;&nbsp;'+closetab+'</li>');
    $("#tabcontent").append('<p id="c'+count+'">Tab Content </p>');

    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
    $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");

    $("#t"+count).bind("click", function() {
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $("#close"+count).bind("click", function() {
        // activate the previous tab
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
        $("#c"+count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#c"+count).remove();
        return false;
    });
}
});
```

MY NEW EDİT
Visit jsfiddle [jsfiddle.net/datakolay/33aM3/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/datakolay/33aM3/8/)

```
 $(function() {  
 $('#tabcontent p').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
    $(".ntabs").filter(':lt(1)').addClass("ctab");

    $("#addtab").click(function() {
     $("#tabcontent p").hide();
      var dataString = '';
             $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "add_tab.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html)
                 {
                  $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                  $("#t"+count).addClass("ctab");
                  $("#tabcontent p").hide();
                  $("#c"+count).fadeIn('slow');
                 }
              });              
          return false;
    });


    $(".ntabs").bind("click", function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id')
      $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
      $(".ntabs").addClass("ctab");

        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#"+id).addClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $("#c"+id).fadeIn('fast'); 
    });

    $(".close").bind("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
        $("#tabcontent p").hide();
        $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
        $("#c"+id).prev().fadeIn('fast');
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#c"+id).remove();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: "does not work"... What are you doing and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: tab 1 not selected? See jsfiddle pls.

Comment: Are you against using the jquery tabs control? http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

You're only adding the event listener to dynamically added tabs i.e.; tab 2, tab 3, tab 4... since tab 1 is hardcoded into the html opposed to being dynamically loaded in, it's never getting the listener added. Although there are a ton of optimizations I'd add to this, the quick fix is to add.

```
 $("#t1").bind("click", function() {
      $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
      $("#t1").addClass("ctab");
      $("#tabcontent p").hide();
      $("#c1").fadeIn('slow');
 });
```

Comment: i want get default tab in mysql. dont want click to add.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in fact in your HTML not your JQuery.  It appears to work properly (as far as I can tell) if you modify your html from this:

```
<ul id="tabul">
    <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"><a href="" id="addtab">+</a>
        <li id="t1" class="ntabs"> Tab 1<a href="" id="close1" class="close">&times;</a></li>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabcontent">
    <p id="c1">Test</p>    
</div>
```

To this:

```
<ul id="tabul">
    <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"><a href="" id="addtab">+</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabcontent">    
</div>
```

Then, I'd make a small adjustment to your JQuery, change:
`var total_tabs = 1;`
to:
`var total_tabs = 0;`

Next, you'd need to work on the way your JQuery handles closing tabs.  If the first tab is closed, the '+' tab is displayed.  If a tab is closed that's not currently focused, it changes focus to the previous tab of the closed tab.

[JSFiddle with my suggestions.](http://jsfiddle.net/LV3WZ/1/)

**Edit:** I also thought I'd present one more thing.  My assumption is that you're going to have some way to dynamically add content to these tabs; given that, I'd dynamically add the first tab (like my suggestion would do) instead of hard coding it into the html simply due to the fact that your JQuery already works for tabs dynamically added (meaning you're doing something wrong with adding listeners to the static tab).  Just my two cents.

**Edit 2:** To answer your question about how to access your MySQL data from JQuery, you should really google something like `JQuery get data from MySQL database`.  That said, you've added `PHP` to the tags, so we'll assume that's what you want to use.  You need to construct an AJAX call through JQuery to retrieve the information.  Also, you need a PHP script to interact with the server.

PHP Script:

```
<?PHP
    $db_address = 'localhost';
    $db_user= 'root';
    $db_pass= 'password';
    $db_name= 'TabData';
    $db;
    function connect() {
    global $db, $db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_dbname;
        if (!$db) {
            $db = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password);
        }
        if (!$db) { 
            die('Could Not Connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
        } else {
            mysql_select_db($db_dbname);
        }
    }
    function disconnect() {
        global $db;
        if ($db) {
            mysql_close($db);
        }
    }
    function query($query) {
    global $db;
        if (!$db) {
            connect();
            if ($db) {
                return query($query);
            }
        } else {
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            return $result;
        }
    }
    function getTabData($id) {
        $result = query("SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE id = \"".$id."\"");
    }

    $data = array();
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // read JSON from raw POST data

    if (!empty($json)) {
    $data = json_decode($json, true); // decode
    if(isset($data["id"]) && !empty($data["id"])) {
        connect();
        getTabData($data["id"]);
        disconnect();
    }
?>
```

Basically, that code will connect to a database named `TabData` and return in JSON the information from the row in table `tabs` with an ID matching that passed in the AJAX query.

JQuery for creating an AJAX call to the above PHP code (contained in a file named myPHP.php):

```
function updateTab(tabID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myPHP.php",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({id: tabID}),
        success: function (data) {
            var tabData = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each($.parseJSON(data), function() {
                $("#c" + this.id).html("" + this.info);
            });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error: " + "\nXMLHttpRequest status: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + "\nXMLHttpRequest statusText: " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + "\ntextStatus: " + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, that code will connect to a php script named `myPHP.php` and send an AJAX query with the ID of the passed in ID.  Upon successful return of the request, the `success` function will return, which parses the returned data from the PHP script and updated the content page of the appropriate id.  I haven't tested this code (since I don't have a readily available environment); but it is code that I have slightly modified from some of my existing code (thus, it *should* work without too many adjustments).

Comment: friend you don't understand me. İ have default tab get in mysql. After i want add or delete extra tab. see my fiddle pls.

Comment: @datakolay, Sorry, maybe my comment in the edit wasn't clear.  You can still have your default tab get it's content from MySQL.  Use something like `$(#c1).html("information from MySQL");` after you add the first tab dynamically.  I looked at your fiddle, I see no where that it's attempting to gather data from MySQL.